# Azure app service - app not in root directory

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a mono repo with more than one application in it. The application I'm trying to deploy is in the directory rest_api. The deploy as seen in github actions is successful, but start-up fails.

This is my start-up command `gunicorn -w 1 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:app`

This is what the github actions file look like:

```
name: Deploy rest_api (dev) to Azure

env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: 'xxx-rest-api'
  PYTHON_VERSION: '3.11'       

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "dev" ]
  workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v3.0.0
        with:
          python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}
          cache: 'pip'

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        working-directory: rest_api
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
      
      - name: Install dependencies
        working-directory: rest_api    
        run: |
          pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements/base.txt
      
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            rest_api
            !venv/
            !rest_api/venv/

  deploy:
    permissions:
      contents: none
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: rest_api
          
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_A79D58476BA645D1BF1A6116201A6E5F }}
          package: rest_api
```

This is the error:

```
2023-03-27T08:52:28.865320556Z Launching oryx with: create-script -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output /opt/startup/startup.sh -virtualEnvName antenv -defaultApp /opt/defaultsite -userStartupCommand 'gunicorn -w 1 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:app'
2023-03-27T08:52:28.925294508Z Cound not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'
2023-03-27T08:52:28.925870805Z Could not find operation ID in manifest. Generating an operation id...
2023-03-27T08:52:28.925880705Z Build Operation ID: d2e6df02-e71b-45fd-b84c-a0d9d8114831
2023-03-27T08:52:29.307010231Z Oryx Version: 0.2.20230103.1, Commit: df89ea1db9625a86ba583272ce002847c18f94fe, ReleaseTagName: 20230103.1
2023-03-27T08:52:29.354907333Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2023-03-27T08:52:29.472048349Z WARNING: Could not find virtual environment directory /home/site/wwwroot/antenv.
2023-03-27T08:52:29.491003271Z WARNING: Could not find package directory /home/site/wwwroot/__oryx_packages__.
2023-03-27T08:52:30.408188883Z 
2023-03-27T08:52:30.408226683Z Error: class uri 'uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker' invalid or not found: 
2023-03-27T08:52:30.408231383Z 
2023-03-27T08:52:30.408234383Z [Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-03-27T08:52:30.408237183Z   File "/opt/python/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 99, in load_class
2023-03-27T08:52:30.408240383Z     mod = importlib.import_module('.'.join(components))
2023-03-27T08:52:30.408243083Z           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-27T08:52:30.408245783Z   File "/opt/python/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2023-03-27T08:52:30.408248583Z     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2023-03-27T08:52:30.408251383Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-03-27T08:52:30.408262283Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
2023-03-27T08:52:30.408265483Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
2023-03-27T08:52:30.408268383Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1128, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2023-03-27T08:52:30.408271083Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
2023-03-27T08:52:30.408273883Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
2023-03-27T08:52:30.408276583Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
2023-03-27T08:52:30.408279383Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1142, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2023-03-27T08:52:30.408282083Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uvicorn'
2023-03-27T08:52:30.408284783Z ]
```

My hunch is that the error relates to the app and the virtualenv not being in root.

Comment: How you are deploying your Application?

Comment: Can you be more specific? I'm deploying with Github actions and in settings I have this start-up command "gunicorn -w 1 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:app"

Comment: Could you please share the GitHub Repo,so that will be easy to do repro from my end.

Comment: Sorry, it's a private repo. Can you let me know if github actions file look correct given that the application is stored in a folder called rest_api and not in the root of the repo?

Comment: I am having issues with python3.11 on azure web app. May be unrelated to yours, but I tried to deploy my app with python 3.8, lo and behold, all works well. I have just tried python 3.10 and it works too. The problem with py 3.11 was that even though it seemed to install the required packages during build, it did not seem to install it into the right venv, and the "runtime" venv was empty.

Comment: I'm facing same issue with python 3.10 unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was requirements were not in rest_api/requirements.txt but in rest_api/requirements/requirements.txt.